# In Craft 4, how can I disable the SSL local issuer certificate verification for any cURL requests?

Tags: craft4, security, ssl

In Craft CMS 4, for testing purpose only in a local environment, how can I disable the SSL verification (probably using `verify_peer` and `verify_peer_name` set to `false`) to all cURL requests, and particularly for those done from any plugins?

For reference :

- I'm using MAMP Pro on Mac OS, but failed to make it works as expected even if
  solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67228537/mamp-local-development-curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-iss)
- This ticket follow an open discussion
  [here](https://github.com/spacecatninja/craft-imager-x/issues/221)